# In this scenario is a many-to-many SQL table relationship the right solution?

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I have Subscribers, SKUs, and Subscribers To SKUs. The SKUs table will be around 75,000 - 100,000 entries, and each subscriber could subscribe to any/all of them. So the Subscribers To SKUs table could get ridiculously large. Is there a better way to approach this other than a many-to-many table relationship?

Comment: This seems like the best solution to me.

Comment: just have couple of extra columns and if subscriber is subscribing to all then just add one flag into that column instead of inserting 75000 to n times.

Comment: I doubt there is a way to avoid the associative table, but perhaps there are patterns to the subscriptions that would allow you to create subscription groups shared by many subscribers. But that would of course introduce yet another associative table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A many-to-many table is the right approach. This is how such relationships are modelled in a relational database.

If this table is indexed correctly, even with millions of records you shouldn't have performance issues.